# Flask Application Circular Dependencies

Tags: python, flask, model, flask-restful

I am developing a Flask application, and I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
  File "app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from endpoints.users.resource import UserResource
  File "{basedir}/endpoints/users/resource.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .model import User
  File "{basedir}/endpoints/users/model.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "{basedir}/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from endpoints.users.resource import UserResource
ImportError: cannot import name 'UserResource' from 'endpoints.users.resource' ({basedir}/endpoints/users/resource.py)
```

I believe it is due to a circular dependency, from looking at the error, but I can't figure out why, because I think that the order in which I am importing things in my code should have circumvented this issue:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

api = Api(app)
api.prefix = '/api'

from endpoints.users.resource import UserResource

api.add_resource(UserResource, '/users')
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

endpoints/users/model.py:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    # info about the class, requires db
```

endpoints/users/resource.py:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from .model import User
from app import db

class UserResource(Resource):
    def get(self, username=None):
        # get request, requires db and User
```

In app.py, since I am importing from endpoints.users.resource after db is created, shouldn't that circumvent the circular dependency?

In addition, I can run this with `flask run` but when I try to use `python app.py`, then it gives me the above error.  Why would these give different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So on `from endpoints.users.resource import UserResource` line python tries to import `from app import db` line to `app.py` which causes `app` reference to itself, which is not good at all.

One workaround to solve circual import errors in Flask is using `init_app` function which exists in most of Flask apps. So just create `database` file like this:

database.py

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from database import db
from endpoints.users.resource import UserResource

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(Config)
db.init_app(app)

api = Api(app)
api.prefix = '/api'



api.add_resource(UserResource, '/users')
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

endpoints/users/model.py:

```py
from database import db

class User(db.Model):
    # info about the class, requires db
```

endpoints/users/resource.py:

```py
from flask_restful import Resource
from endpoints.users.model import User
from database import db

class UserResource(Resource):
    def get(self, username=None):
        # get request, requires db and User
```

Note that I rewrote your imports from related, so don't forget to add `__init__.py` files
Your structure will be like this:

```
.
├── app.py
└── database.py/
└── endpoints/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── users/
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── model.py
            └── resource.py
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What are the ```__init__.py``` files for?

Comment: @user11799 They're to help python indexing modules. So, when you launch `app.py`, python goes recursively in every sub directory and checks for these files, and you only can import modules, in which directory you have `__init__.py` .The good practise is to have `__init__.py` files in every subdirectory (but not in root). Files could be empty.

Comment: @user11799 if you don't have these files, the only way to import is relative one (like you did with `from .model import User`), but the con of this method is that you can't import from parent directory. In my example, we wanted to import `database` file which was 2 levels upper than `model`