# Unable to import models from the local python file

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, conda

I have installed flask and flask-sqlalchemy in my base environment of the conda. I defined the models in separate file (model.py), when I am trying to import it in my app.py file it's throwing the following error

[image]

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots of your code, copy it and use a markdown to format it. It is helping a lot to answer your question faster! c:

Comment: @Alveona I know that, the concern was with import so i pasted the screenshot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `from model import User`, you cause python to import `from app import db`, i.e. import `app` into `app`, which is not allowed in python

Please, take a look at this answer, I wrote it pretty straightforward how to solve this problem with `flask-sqlalchemy`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62991785/10468419